# Not all namespaces coming across over WCF reference

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have 3 projects in my solution.

- A common class library named ReportBuilderLib
- A WPF application named ReportClient that contains a service reference to a 3rd project -
- A WCF web service which contains web methods for my application to call upon.

Initially when setting up both the service and the application i added the common library to references on both projects so that i could use the classes i needed to in both.

It quickly cam clear that in the process of generating the code to use the web methods in my client application, it was automatically importing certain namespaces that i had used in service application.

This was throwing me conflicting reference warnings as they were effectively being imported from two separate resources.

I then removed the reference to the library in my report client, i could see that VS was only importing one out of the two namespaces my client requires. Both of which are returned by methods in my ServiceContract!

Having looked at the generated code for the client, it seems to be re-creating the classes i have included in the library and providing only the public properties for access.

Is it possible to use librarys like i am trying to with WCF. Or should i scrap the common library idea and simply create some data transfer classes on the service end?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference the common library on both ends, but it may be useful and less of a headache to implement data transfer classes like you suggested. Using special classes (or serialization like JSON) to send and receive data from the service would make it easier for you to re-use the service for multiple client projects.

Any time you decrease the coupling between layers of an application you make it easier to implement changes/upgrades in the future :)

Comment: Ideally i would like to use a common library, the only issue is that any of the classes the service reference creates, it creates using the same namespace as the one the client is referencing, creating a conflict i cannot deal with. I'll have a look into using JSON or XML as a replacement to sending non built-in-types.